# Change text in a PickerView

Tags: translation, pickerview

I used this code in `Objective C` to change language in a `PickerView`:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    self.dicke  = [[NSArray alloc]
                   initWithObjects:@"0.0",@"0.5",@"1.0",@"1.5",@"2.0",@"2.5",@"3.0",@"4.0",@"5.0",@"6.0",@"8.0",@"10.0",@"12.0",@"15.0",@"20.0", nil];


    NSString *userLocale = [[NSLocale currentLocale] localeIdentifier];
    NSLog(@"%@", userLocale);


    if ([userLocale isEqualToString:@"de_DE"]) {
        self.Material  = [[NSArray alloc]

                          initWithObjects:@"Stahl",@"Aluminium",@"Edelstahl",@"Kupfer", nil];
     }
     else
         self.Material  = [[NSArray alloc]

                          initWithObjects:@"Steel",@"Aluminum",@"Stainless",@"Copper", nil];
}
```

How can i do this in `Swift`, or is there another way to translate text in a `PickerView`. Sorry for this stupid question but I´m really a beginner with `Swift`.

Answer (score 0):

Ok,

i fixed it with:

```
var  material = [NSLocalizedString ("Steel", comment: ""),NSLocalizedString ("Aluminum", comment: ""),NSLocalizedString ("Stainless", comment: ""),NSLocalizedString ("Copper", comment: "")]
```

and use localizable.strings. That works fine!

Answer (score 0):

**In Swift 3.0**

```
func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, viewForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int, reusing view: UIView?) -> UIView {
        let pickerLabel = UILabel()
        pickerLabel.textColor = (row == pickerView.selectedRow(inComponent: component)) ? UIColor.white : UIColor.white
        pickerLabel.text =  arrAgeLimite[row]
        pickerLabel.font.withSize(90)
        pickerLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.center
        return pickerLabel
    }
```